# What is the difference between Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) vs [...args]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, rest-parameters

I know that `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is used to create arguments into a real array as shown below:

```
function foo() {
  // convert arguments to an array:
  var argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // . . . foo's logic . . .
}
```

and I can also use the `spread operator` to achieve the same functionality as below

```
function foo(...argsArray) {
  // . . . foo's logic . . .
}
```

Apart from less verbose in using `spread operator`, what are the differences between both approaches?

Comment: I think they're exactly the same in the case of `arguments`.

Comment: in the first case, args is an object  and it is an array like

Comment: in the second case, the spread operator is a pure array

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHussien `argsArray` is a standard pure array too.

Comment: check this for arguments https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: One difference that will almost never be relevant is that when you use rest syntax, you no longer have a "simple" argument list, so the argument variables and the `arguments` object items are no longer bound together

Comment: I think in the function foo, it becomes a rest parameter not a spread operator.

Comment: This is not spread operator, but Rest parameters syntax, introduced exactly to reduce the boilerplate you used to convert arguments into array  [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, both variants should work the same.

The arguments object was mainly used before rest parameters and the spread operator was a thing. According to MDN, it shouldn't be used in modern JavaScript anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments